# How to select radio button on condition using Prime NG <p-radioButton />

Tags: angular, primeng

I have created radio buttons using prime NG , By default Radio button "Yes" and "Drop down" are selected by default , if you see my code if i select "NO" then in Answer Format the "Checkbox" will get replaced with "Number" , now i am trying to do is when i select "NO" then "Number" should get selected and if i select "Yes" then "Drop down" should be selected. I have tried but not getting the result as expected.

```
          <div class="input-row full-width" >
            <div class="left-col">
               Allow Multiple Answer
            </div>
            <div class="right-col radio-btn">
             <p-radioButton name="multiple answer" formControlName="allow_multiple_answer" value="1"
               label="Yes" class="radio"></p-radioButton>
             <p-radioButton name="multiple answer" formControlName="allow_multiple_answer" value="0"
               label="No" class="radio"></p-radioButton>
            </div>
          </div>

     
          <div class="input-row" >
            <div class="left-col">
              Answer Format
            </div>
            <div class="right-col radio-btn">
              <p-radioButton name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="0" label="Drop down"
                class="radio">
              </p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton *ngIf="(f.allow_multiple_answer.value == '1')
                name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="1" label="Checkbox" class="radio">
              </p-radioButton>
              <p-radioButton *ngIf="(f.allow_multiple_answer.value == '0') 
                name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="2" label=" Number" class="radio">
              </p-radioButton>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Comment: I have sorted it out , using onChange() ,i have used formGroup to get the formControlName =answer_format ans set the value using .setVlaues to "0" or "2"

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<div class="input-row full-width" >
  <div class="left-col">
      Allow Multiple Answer
  </div>
  <div class="right-col radio-btn">
    <p-radioButton name="multiple answer" formControlName="allow_multiple_answer" value="1"
      label="Yes" class="radio"></p-radioButton>
    <p-radioButton name="multiple answer" formControlName="allow_multiple_answer" value="0"
      label="No" class="radio"></p-radioButton>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="input-row" >
  <div class="left-col">
    Answer Format
  </div>
  <div class="right-col radio-btn">
    <p-radioButton name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="0" label="Drop down" class="radio">
    </p-radioButton>
    <p-radioButton *ngIf="(f.allow_multiple_answer.value == 1)"  name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="1" label="Checkbox" class="radio">
    </p-radioButton>
    <p-radioButton *ngIf="(f.allow_multiple_answer.value == 0)" name="answer_format_button" formControlName="answer_format" value="2" label=" Number" class="radio">
    </p-radioButton>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i want "Number" radio button to be checked when i select "No" and if i select "Yes " then "Drop down" radio button to checked